# Can I use AIC or BIC to compare models fitted to the same data, but different weighting?

Tags: time-series, model-comparison, sample-weighting

E.g. I have a time series data from day 1 up to day T.

I want to compare models with Yt~Xt, with

1. equal weight of all data set
2. put more weight (like exponential decay) for the day more close to T

Can I use AIC or BIC to compare these models?